# Strange behavior of web stress tests

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, lxc, benchmark

After some server configuration, i decided to do a stress test using **siege**.

2 front servers in lxc containers, load balancing nginx - on the host machine.
*(if need, I add nginx and sysctl configs later)*

Host machine - dedicated server on OVH:

```
Intel  Xeon E5
2x E5-2630v3 2.4 GHz (32 cores at all)
128 GB of RAM DDR3
2x 480GB SSD (RAID 1)
```

Some parameters of containers:

```
8 cores, 8192 cpu units per core
8 GB RAM
```

In lxc conteiners - php + static (images, css, js). Future load will be on static content output. The test was conducted on a static page with js, css and images.

In general, the test results are different, and strange behavior:

`siege http://example.com/some_url -r50 -c250`

test #1:

```
Transactions: 12451 hits
Availability: 99.61 %
Elapsed time: 36.84 secs
Data transferred: 80.52 MB
Response time: 0.06 secs
Transaction rate: 337.98 trans/sec
Throughput: 2.19 MB/sec
Concurrency: 21.43
Successful transactions: 12451
Failed transactions: 49
Longest transaction: 1.18
Shortest transaction: 0.04
```

test #2, same parameters

```
Transactions: 12152 hits
Availability: 97.22 %
Elapsed time: 200.90 secs
Data transferred: 29.16 MB
Response time: 1.15 secs
Transaction rate: 60.49 trans/sec
Throughput: 0.15 MB/sec
Concurrency: 69.67
Successful transactions: 12152
Failed transactions: 348
Longest transaction: 63.40
Shortest transaction: 0.16
```

In the first case, a good performance, sometime during the second results worse and strange behavior, namely:
It begins test - CPU of each container is loaded on ~50%, but load decreases over time, and the response time -  increases, appears connection timeouts. Then the speed is increased, and those "waves" before end of the test. During tests no anomaly in top/htop, disks I/O or servers logs.
Thanks in advance for your advice;)

Comment: The question should indicate what software is running in the lxc containers that nginx is load balancing. A jvm app, for instance, may have decided to collect some garbage, a frequent occurrence during load testing. Also a test against the nginx itself just returning a plain text response without load balancing/proxying would identify or eliminate nginx from consideration as the culprit.

Comment: What is this testing? Static web page serving? Where is it running, your own hardware? Is the machine dedicated? Far more information needed if you want useful help.

Comment: I added a description of soft in containers. Also add parameters of host machine and lxc containers.